# What is wrong with this Moq unit test that is supposed to (fake) retrieve a list?

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I am trying to test this method that is meant to retrieve data out of a database and store them into a List<>. I have made this fake list that is meant to be found by the method. However, instead the method retrieves the actual database and returns the actual amount. What am I missing?

```cs
    public class GetAllPhonesTests
    {
        private readonly Mock<IRepository<Phone>> _mockPhoneRepository;
        private readonly IPhoneService _phoneService;

        private readonly List<Phone> _fakePhones = new()
        {
            new Phone() { Id = 1, Brand = "Herp", Type = "Police" },
            new Phone() { Id = 2, Brand = "Derp", Type = "Fireman" },
            new Phone() { Id = 3, Brand = "Zerp", Type = "Nurse" },
            new Phone() { Id = 4, Brand = "Flurp", Type = "Doctor" },
            new Phone() { Id = 5, Brand = "Terp", Type = "Teacher" }
        };

        public GetAllPhonesTests()
        {
            _mockPhoneRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Phone>>();
            _phoneService = new PhoneService(_mockPhoneRepository.Object);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Should_ReturnFullList_When_Called()
        {
            //Arrange
            _mockPhoneRepository.Setup(x => x.GetRecords(It.IsAny<SqlCommand>())).Returns(_fakePhones);

            //Act
            List<Phone> actual = _phoneService.GetAllPhones();

            //Assert
            actual.Count.Should().Be(_fakePhones.Count); 
        }
    }
```

additional from the service:

```cs
        public List<Phone> GetAllPhones()
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM phones INNER JOIN Brands ON Brands.BrandID=phones.BrandId;";
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                return (List<Phone>)GetRecords(command);
            }
        }
```

additional from the repo:

```cs
        public IEnumerable<T> GetRecords(SqlCommand command)
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            List<T> list = new();

            try
            {
                command.Connection = _connection;
                _connection.Open();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(PopulateRecord(reader));
                }

                reader.NextResult();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        GetDataCount(Convert.ToInt32(reader["Count"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
                Status(false, "");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Status(true, ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
                _connection.Close();
            }

            return list;
        }
```

Comment: When you debug, when you get into GetAllPhones, at the point of making the call from the repo for GetRecords is that showing the use of the mock repo?

Comment: Could you show the implementation of your GetAllPhones() method?

Comment: No, the call goes into the actual repo.

Comment: is GetRecords on the repository and GetAllPhones on the service? because from the pasted code it looks like GetAllPhones is calling a method on itself. So, is GetAllPhones on the repository?

Comment: You don't need to initialize (`new`) a readonly field twice: you now has a default assignment *and* initialization in de constructor. And might I suggest using Entity Framework, or at least Dapper? Raw SQL is risky.

Comment: Apologies for it being unclear, yes the getrecords is on the repo and the getallphones is on the service.

Comment: You need to give us a [mcve]. Somehow a `Repository` is used in the constructor of `PhoneService`, but the code you show doesn't actually show that the repository is being used. Instead is seems that `PhoneService` has its own method `GetRecords`. I see no reference to a `_repository` dependency field....

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to use anything other than sql.

Comment: If you're mocking `GetRecords` in the repo there's no reason to include that method and its code in the question. The test isn't supposed to execute it - it's supposed to mock it. Including the repo interface that you're mocking would be more helpful. If, as you say, the service is calling `GetRecords` on the repo (not on itself) the code should indicate that. It's hard to help if you're saying the code does one thing but we can see that it does something else.

Comment: The difficulty in answering the question is because assuming that all else is normal, the way you're setting up and using the mock is correct. If in doubt you can prove that to yourself by just creating a temporary test that does nothing but call the mock. You'll see that it returns the expected result. That means the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be in the order of your setup, as it should be done before you add the repository object to the mock service. Can you try to change it to this:

```
public class GetAllPhonesTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IRepository<Phone>> _mockPhoneRepository;
    private readonly IPhoneService _phoneService;

    private readonly List<Phone> _fakePhones = new()
    {
        new Phone() { Id = 1, Brand = "Herp", Type = "Police" },
        new Phone() { Id = 2, Brand = "Derp", Type = "Fireman" },
        new Phone() { Id = 3, Brand = "Zerp", Type = "Nurse" },
        new Phone() { Id = 4, Brand = "Flurp", Type = "Doctor" },
        new Phone() { Id = 5, Brand = "Terp", Type = "Teacher" }
    };

    public GetAllPhonesTests()
    {
        _mockPhoneRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Phone>>();
        _mockPhoneRepository.Setup(x => x.GetRecords(It.IsAny<SqlCommand> 
         ())).Returns(_fakePhones);
        _phoneService = new PhoneService(_mockPhoneRepository.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Should_ReturnFullList_When_Called()
    {
        //Act
        List<Phone> actual = _phoneService.GetAllPhones();

        //Assert
        actual.Count.Should().Be(_fakePhones.Count); 
    }
}
```

Your service should also be using DI to get the repository implementation used, for example:

```
    private readonly IRepository<Phone> _phoneRepo;

    public PhoneService(IRepository<Phone> phoneRepo){
        _phoneRepo = phoneRepo;
    }

    public List<Phone> GetAllPhones()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM phones INNER JOIN Brands ON Brands.BrandID=phones.BrandId;";
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            return (List<Phone>)_phoneRepo.GetRecords(command);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's far worse that that. Look at his code: The phoneservice doesn't use the repository, but instead has a local GetRecords...

Comment: Unfortunately, like my use of sql, I am also not (yet) allowed to use DI. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Then that is the problem, even though you are mocking the repository you are not using that implementation in your service, even without DI you can still have the repository as shown above and pass it manually, try to implement the service in the way I show above and see if your test works, without DI what you would have to do is provide an instance of repository every time the service is used, for ex: new PhoneService(new Repository<Phone>())

Comment: The setup just has to be done before the method is called. It doesn't matter if it's done before or after the mock is used as a constructor argument.